# Increment for-loop by 2 in Scala

Tags: scala, for-loop

How do I increment the loop by 2 as equivalent to this in Java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i+=2)
```

Right now in Scala I have:

```
for (a <- 0 to max)
```

For a fact `max` will always be even. I don't know how to increment the counter to 2 in each loop.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try `for (a <- 0 until max by 2)`

Comment: Using `to` will include `max` which is not what the question asks.

Answer (score 23):

Note the difference between `to` and `until`. With a strict `i < max` you will want until.

```
val max = 10

scala> for(i <- 0 until max by 2)
     | println(i)
0
2
4
6
8

scala> for(i <- 0 to max by 2)
     | println(i)
0
2
4
6
8
10
```

Answer (score 4):

Surely

```
(0 until max by 2)  foreach {...}
```

will suffice.

Answer (score 4):

**This way you can use scala for loop like java one.**

```
object Example extends App {
    for(i <-0 to 20 by 2) {
        println("Value of i = "+ i)
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Value of i = 0
Value of i = 2
Value of i = 4
Value of i = 6
Value of i = 8
Value of i = 10
Value of i = 12
Value of i = 14
Value of i = 16
Value of i = 18
Value of i = 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsurprisingly easy:

```
scala> for (a <- 0 until 10 by 2) yield a
// Vector(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (a <- 0 to max by 2) yield a
```